# Laravel belongsToMany and Eloquent query

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to get a list of the ID's of the users who read a particular magazine.

> things table (magazines)

```
id
name
```

> thing_progresses

```
id
progress_value
```

> thingprogress_thing

```
id
thing_progress_id (FK from thing_progresses table)
thing_id (FK from things table)
user_id (FK from users table)
```

Thing Model

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thing extends Model
{
    public function readers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\ThingProgress', 'thingprogress_thing');
    }
}
```

My application

```
$readers = Thing::with(array('readers' => function($query) use ($id) {
$query->where('thing_progress_id', '1');
}))->find($id);
```

View

```
@foreach($readers as $reader)
    {{$reader->user_id}}
@endforeach
```

Here's the error I got.

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/master/resources/views/frontend/thing/book/index.blade.php)
```

Comment: Have you dumped `$readers`? Is it a collection or a single object?

Answer (score 0):

To get attributes that are a pivot table (and that are not the FK's for the relationship) you have to tell Laravel to get them.

Just add `withPivot('user_id')` to the relationship i.e.

```
public function readers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\ThingProgress', 'thingprogress_thing')->withPivot('user_id');
}
```

Then you can access it with:

```
$reader->pivot->user_id
```

Hope this helps!